# Bootstrap Span does not align on page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap in my MVC 4 application to align,

My page loads inside Kendo panel

Most of the time it works correctly,
but some times the span is not aligned properly when the page loads for the first time, after i manually resize the window the spans align correctly.

---

Here is  what i am trying to achieve(This works well most of the time)

```
span1  span2
span3  span4
```

This is what i get

```
 s  p  a  n  1
 s  p  a  n  2
 s  p  a  n  3
 s  p  a  n  4
```

HTML inside razor

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span5">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                   <!-- Form elements removed-->
                         </div>
                     </div>
                <div class="span5">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                   <!-- Form elements removed-->
                        </div>
                </div>
          </div>
       <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span5">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                   <!-- Form elements removed-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="span5">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                   <!-- Form elements removed-->
                        </div>
                  </div>
          </div>
```

> Additional info
>
> Browser IE 9
>
> Bootstrap version 2

Comment: It looks like you're getting the mobile css layout. Just noticed is this your full markup? if yes you are missing the close tag for container-fluid.

Comment: Hi.. Yes.. i am getting mobile layout... but the issue is not consistent also, when i resize my browser the span align's properly. the code posted is not my full mark up i have the close tag for my container - fluid.

Comment: Have you modified bootstrap source files ?

Comment: Nope.. i didn't modify the source files.